# Make the sum in a text type cell of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

This question concerns Excel.  If I have a cell of type text, in which I go to insert more dates with hours for each date, formatted as follows:

```
06/05/2019 Hours taken: 1,23

06/09/2019 Hours taken: 0,12

06/10/2019 Hours taken: 0,45

06/11/2019 Hours taken: 1,59
```

Of course everything will be considered as text.  But if I wanted to make the sum of all the hours, is there a way to do it?

Comment: is **1,23** one hour 23 minutes ??

Comment: @garys-student Yes, exactly

Comment: 1. Can you clarify whether 1,23 is 1.23 hours (approx 1 hr 14 min) or 1 hr 23 min; that still isn't clear?  2. In your locale, is comma used as a decimal separator?  3. Are the 4 lines shown in the example the contents of one cell, four cells, or 7 cells (those four strings + empty cells between)?  4. Are the values shown at the end of each string (e.g., 1,23), values you are calculating somewhere else and you just want to display them in a specific format as part of the string, or calculations you want to perform as (cont'd)

Comment: an expression within the string and format the result as part of the string, or you want to extract and sum those values and show the result somewhere else (another cell)?

Comment: @fixer1234 1,23 is 1 hr 23 min ; in my locale comma is used as a decimal separator ; the 4 lines shown in the example are the contents of one cell ; I want to extract and sum those values and show the result in another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have Excel 2013+, with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use this array formula:

**EDIT**: *formula changed to account for the times representing `h,mm`*

```
=DOLLARFR(SUM(DOLLARDE(--SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "))," ","</s><s>") &"</s></t>","//s[contains(text(),'taken')]/following-sibling::s[1]"),",","."),60)),60)
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

If your decimal separator is the comma, then you should use:

```
=DOLLARFR(SUM(DOLLARDE(--FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "))," ","</s><s>") &"</s></t>","//s[contains(text(),'taken')]/following-sibling::s[1]"),60)),60)
```

**Algorithm**

- Replace the linefeeds with spaces, and `TRIM` the result so there are only single spaces
- Replace the spaces with tokens, and also add tokens at the start and end, to create a well-formed `XML`
- Return an array of the contents of the node that immediately follows the node containing `taken`.
- In the US, I have to replace the comma with a dot in order to properly interpret the numeric value.  You may or may not need to do that in your locale.
- Apply a double unary to convert the text representation of the numbers into real numbers
- Use the `DOLLARDE` and `DOLLARFR` functions to be able to change a number like `1.23` representing `1 hr 23 min` into a fraction that can be added, and then back to a decimal representing `h.mm` *It could also be changed to a "real" excel time and formatted, but you have not clarified your requirements*
- `SUM` the resultant array.

[image]

Comment: the formula contains an error https://imgur.com/otblRKZ

Comment: @nicovon Why do you think the formula contains an error?  Clearly, it works for me as seen by the screenshot showing the correct result with the formula. Please provide more specific information. (`CHAR` is a valid function in US English Excel)

Comment: I have italian Excel

Comment: @nicovon Then possibly you have not translated the formula correctly. According to the Excel formula translator, the Italian CHAR is CODICE.CARATT. Also, be sure you have Excel 2013+ with the FILTERXML function (Italian: possibly: FILTRO.XML. And you may need to change the argument separators to the semi-colon; and you can probably omit the SUBSTITUTE that is changing the decimal separator from comma to dot. – Ron Rosenfeld 8 mins ago

Comment: @nicovon According to the Excel Translator, the Italian version of that formula (with the `SUBSTITUTE` function changing the comma to dot removed, would be `=VALUTA.FRAZ(SOMMA(VALUTA.DEC(--FILTRO.XML("<t><s>"&SOSTITUISCI(ANNULLA.SPAZI(SOSTITUISCI(A1;CODICE.CARATT(10);" "));" ";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[contains(text(),'taken')]/following-sibling::s[1]");60));60)`  Don't forget to enter it as an **array-formula** as described above.

Comment: @nicovon Probably just replace `taken` with `ore`

Comment: does not work. if I use this text https://imgur.com/VhwhNXn how does the formula become?

Comment: @nicovon What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  It returns the correct result here in English Excel when I set my decimal separator to the dot.

Comment: It gives me a wrong result

Comment: @nicovon What result does it give, and what result do you expect?

Comment: @nicovon If your "wrong result" is the first value (`3,40` in your second example, or `1,23` in the example in your question, then the problem is that you are not understanding how to enter an array formula. Please re-read that part of my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. after modifying the formula, I had forgotten that it is a CSE formula. I'm noticing that the formula works whether it's present ":" after "ore", or not.

Comment: Can I ask you for another help? despite the format of the cell where I entered the formula, it is a general format, the formula works very well. the problem arises when I have to subtract the result obtained from a total number of hours. according to your experience, what format must the cells have to carry out this subtraction?

Comment: here is an example. with both cells in the general format: 18 - 9,45 = 8,55. it should be 8,15

Comment: Formatting won't help. The decimal representation of `h,mm` will result in math operations being done in base 10, but you really want base 60.  You can either do a lot of back and forth between the two bases, as I did with the `DOLLARDE...DOLLARFR` functions, or just convert them to real Excel times.  Converting from decimal representation to real times, if you can't figure it out, would be best answered in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming US Locale and time format of *h,mm*, with data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,4),",",":") & ":00")
```

and set the format to a time format.  Then copy downwards.  In another cell enter:

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: OPs location is Italy. I assume 1,23 hours means 1 hour and 0.23*60 minutes. 1,23 is a quite common format when you calculate work times.

Comment: @garys-student Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.  all values ​​are in the same cell with a carriage return